# kendo treeview image associated with my element disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a kendo treeview, I don't know why but the drag and drop doesn't work properly anymore. When I drag and drop it to somewhere in my tree, the image associated with my span disappear. The html of the element I have selected transform into a simple span and lost my image class and the span field (span data-field data-bind...).

Thank you in advance

Comment: can't help you without the code

Comment: It is work-related, I am not too sure what to put. I am scared to get scolded.